# When synchronizing in eclipse pdt - getting a blank gray window when comparing versions of a php file

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, subversive, synchronize

I've installed Eclipse PDT Helios SR1 GTK for 64bit Linux (Ubuntu Maverick clean install).
I added the Subversive plugin for using Subversion, and installed the SVNKit 1.3.2 connector.
I'm using Sun's java and not the OpenJDK version.

When I synchronize a php project, and double click a php file for comparing the differences I made compared to the base revision - it opens a window of a compared file, but the window is empty - I see the gray background as if no file is opened.

When I open files which are not set as a PHP file, it works fine.
(If I'll take a file with a .module extension and define it as a php file in the Content Types preferences pane, it will act badly as described above. If I'll remove this definition, it will work [as if I compared a plain text file]).

Anybody has any idea why is this happening ?
If I missed any important information that will help diagnose or solve this issue, lemme know and I'll add it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326194

There's a fix that you can install, although it's on a non-release update site.

Unbelievably, they still haven't fixed it in the main update site.

Comment: The non-release update site is: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/