# Eclipse problem with subclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

Me and my partner installed from scratch eclipse with subclipse...But neither me or he can compare the files!!
Right Clicking a file >Compare with > Revision  or anything we tried in order to make a comparison it failed and always will!
I get an error of java.lang.nullpointerexception and nothing more!
Here is what i get from the log

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2
>   2010-11-20 04:36:28.653 !MESSAGE
>   Problems occurred when invoking code
>   from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.core.format.FormatPreferencesSupport.verifyValidity(FormatPreferencesSupport.java:100)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.core.format.FormatPreferencesSupport.getIndentationChar(FormatPreferencesSupport.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.configuration.PHPStructuredTextViewerConfiguration.getIndentPrefixes(PHPStructuredTextViewerConfiguration.java:448)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.configure(StructuredTextViewer.java:311)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.MergeSourceViewer.configure(MergeSourceViewer.java:542)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer$ContributorInfo.internalSetDocument(TextMergeViewer.java:546)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer$ContributorInfo.setDocument(TextMergeViewer.java:434)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer.updateContent(TextMergeViewer.java:2569)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.ContentMergeViewer.internalRefresh(ContentMergeViewer.java:814)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.ContentMergeViewer.inputChanged(ContentMergeViewer.java:704)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareViewerSwitchingPane.java:276)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareContentViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareContentViewerSwitchingPane.java:158)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.internalSetContentPaneInput(CompareEditorInput.java:844)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.access$8(CompareEditorInput.java:842)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput$11.run(CompareEditorInput.java:785)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.feed1(CompareEditorInput.java:772)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.access$3(CompareEditorInput.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput$5.open(CompareEditorInput.java:657)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.compare.CompareViewerPane.open(CompareViewerPane.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When synchronizing in eclipse pdt - getting a blank gray window when comparing versions of a php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157036/when-synchronizing-in-eclipse-pdt-getting-a-blank-gray-window-when-comparing-ve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found that my link is posted to the bug! 
The boredom of the programmer who ignored this bug may cause ULTRA SEVERE problems to other people...
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326194

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and solved it by going Help -> Install new software -> Enter:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/

And install. (This is the same procedure as described in the above links).

Compare works again!

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[When synchronizing in eclipse pdt - getting a blank gray window when comparing versions of a php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157036/when-synchronizing-in-eclipse-pdt-getting-a-blank-gray-window-when-comparing-ve)